# Endpoint method receiving modified string parameter

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am developing a Appengine connected android application. I have and endpoint method searchBook(String bookName) as defined below:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "searchBook")
public List<Book> searchBook(@Named("bookName") String bookName) {

    //Codes for searching book by setting filter for the received book name
}
```

And I am calling this method from client app as:

```
 endoint.searchBook("test book 2").execute();
```

My problem is that the string received in endpoint method is "test%20book%202", which is not the original string but some additional characters in between words.Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it is getting added.
May be, you can decode the received string for removing %20 etc URL encoding related symbols.

```
String newString = java.net.URLDecoder.decode( bookName, "UTF-8")
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

http://icfun.blogspot.in/2009/08/java-urlencode-and-urldecode-options.html

Comment: thanks!useful information.In my case, I had found out solution by calling replace("%20"," ") function on the string and it worked. But this seems to be a more versatile solution.

Comment: Correct.. decoding will handle all use-cases. %20 is just for space character

Comment: so, there is no loophole in the approach i followed?